# Remove WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions from Android Project

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play

I removed the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions from the project's `AndroidMainfest.xml` and `AssemblyInfo.cs` files.

I uploaded the .apk to Play Store and in the Bundle permissions the Write & Read permissions were showing up.

Then I analyzed the `.apk` using `Analyze APK` feature in Android Studio, and in that, `AndroidMainfest.xml` has `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Though, I ask for `CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Storage)` on run time, but when I removed it and Analyzed the APK, still it includes `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions in Manifest file.

I then add the `android:requiredFeature="false"` flag to Write & Read permissions like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:requiredFeature="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:requiredFeature="false" />
```

And when I Analyzed the APK again, Write & Read permissions are there with `android:requiredFeature="false"`. But on Play Store, in the Bundle permissions they are there as before.

I don't know why these permissions are ending up there?

Comment: They can be merged from the dependent library. You can check if any library you are using have those permissions in their Manifest file.

Comment: @Sergey thanks a lot for the comment.. I resolved it. please check my answer below..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*@Sergey Comment: They can be merged from the dependent library. You can check if any library you are using have those permissions in their Manifest file.*

I looked into it and found this article *[How Libraries can silently add permissions to your Android App](https://medium.com/glucosio-project/how-libraries-can-silently-add-permissions-to-your-android-app-620911d7de6c)* and the *[Fix](https://github.com/Glucosio/glucosio-android/commit/2f48b314b82a252df2ca20cd2811c464e965887b)*. **It Worked**.

But I'm using camera, and I was storing these pictures in the `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)`. Which requires `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions.

So, I replace the path with `FileSystem.CacheDirectory` and it worked (Intenral Storage doesn't requires Read and Write Permissions in Manifest file).